How to create model to determine transition between sleep and wake states in near real time?
I want to be able to determine the time when someone woke up / went to sleep based on step data. Like the amount of steps taken in 10 minute intervals over the last X amount of hours. I want a model that can determine when someone transitions from one state into the other. And I want it to be able to base this off of the past few hours of data so that it has enough context to confidently say that the transition has occurred. Ideally, the model should be able to determine a state transition within 30 minutes to an hour of it actually occurring. So if the data is given to the model 30 minutes after someone went to sleep, the model should recognize that a transition into sleep occurred based on the past X amount of hours of context data. I also want to incorporate the time of day to better the classification. I understand this may not be very accurate but I am doing it to learn. My research tells me a LSTM model may be best but any thoughts or points would be of great help. Thank you very much.
